# How to save Phylo tree to file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm struggling to save a Phylo tree to file. It shows up in Jupyter Notebook but the file is blank.

I've looked through a lot of of documentation as well as Googled a lot... How do I get the tree to print to file?

```
# Read in alignment
aln = AlignIO.read("v4.fna", "fasta")

# Calculate the distance matrix
calculator = DistanceCalculator('identity')
dm = calculator.get_distance(aln)

# Visualize neighbor joined tree
constructor = DistanceTreeConstructor()
tree = constructor.nj(dm)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20), dpi=100)
axes = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
Phylo.draw(tree, axes=axes, label_func=get_label)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('v4.png')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had to specify False for `do_show` in the `Phylo.draw` call.

```
Phylo.draw(tree, axes=axes, label_func=get_label, do_show=False)
```

I also took down `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `plt.show()` will make it unavailable for saving afterwards.
I could not find a specific explanation for this in the docs.

Try doing `plt.savefig('v4.png')` before you do `plt.show()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this results in a blank figure as well.